# Ignore event system trigger when removing older versions

Tags: event-system

When you remove an older version of a component from its history in Tridion, it seems it will trigger the event system's OnComponentDeletePost method.

We have a situation where removing components of a certain schema type in the GUI will also remove some other components related to this component. This is good, but should not occur when items are removed from the component's history, such as when running the purge tool.

Is there any way to detect a component was fully deleted or if a version was deleted in its history when running code in an event system's OnComponentDeletePost method?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, before the execution of any code in event handler. You should check the version of the component.

You can get the version of a component by `component.Version`.

I haven't run the code for this but I guess it should work.

**UPDATE:**

As correctly pointed out by @Rick in the comment. the version 0 represents the checked out version of the component. So Please use `component.Id.IsVerionless` to check the version less item.

Thanks Rick

Comment: Agree that you should check the version of the item to be deleted, but version 0 does not represent the latest version of an item, but the checked-out/editable/dynamic version. That version (which only exist if the item is checked-out) cannot be deleted. You can dinstinguish delete of an entire item from a specific version by the lack of a version number in the items TCM URI (component.Id.IsVerionless)

Answer (score 2):

Rick's comment under Saurabh's seems to be the most appropriate one. Checking for the Component.Id.IsVersionLess flag will give you the info to distinguish between a delete action from the explorer or from the component's history.